# How to make forms inline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i have 3 forms

```html
        <form th:method="get" th:action=="..." th:object="${...}" >
            <input  type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary my-2">
        </form>

        <form th:method="delete" th:action="..." th:object="${...}">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">
        </form>

        <form th:method="put" th:action="..." th:object="${...}">
            <input type="submit" value="Back" class="btn btn-primary my-2">
        </form>
```

How can i make them in one row with bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place all these form elements in a div and add styling to the div as any one of the below. You can use wrap also for the styling.

```
justify-content: center;     /* Pack items around the center */

justify-content: start;      /* Pack items from the start */

justify-content: end;        /* Pack items from the end */


justify-content: flex-start; /* Pack flex items from the start */

justify-content: flex-end;   /* Pack flex items from the end */

justify-content: left;       /* Pack items from the left */

justify-content: right;      /* Pack items from the right */
```

You can go through the documentation for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply wrap them in a `div` and put them in a `flex` row.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <form th:method="get" th:action=="..." th:object="${...}">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary my-2">
  </form>

  <form th:method="delete" th:action="..." th:object="${...}">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">
  </form>

  <form th:method="put" th:action="..." th:object="${...}">
    <input type="submit" value="Back" class="btn btn-primary my-2">
  </form>
  <div>
```